# How to sum up similar variables after several new class() have been generated

Tags: java

Say you define a simple class

```
public class Box {
double width;
}
```

and then in Main you have multiple new classes like

```
Box mybox1 = new Box();
mybox1.width = x
Box mybox2 = new Box();
mybox2.width = y
```

and after n times

```
Box myboxn = new Box()
myboxn.width = n
```

Is there a way to sum up all the *.width with an instruction like:

```
for each .width
total = total + next.box.width?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer nope, how could someone iterate over some thin air?? So store the boxes in a `java.util.List`, then iterate the list

Comment: since you're already looping n times to create the Boxes just add them to a data structure like an Arraylist as you create and set the widths. Then do a for each on the Boxes in the data structure adding the widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking of using a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to hold all of the widths, then summing them in a for each loop:

```
List<Double> widths=new ArrayList<>();

//declare all your new classes in Main and add their widths to the list
Box mybox1 = new Box();
widths.add(mybox1.width);
Box mybox2 = new Box();
widths.add(mybox2.width);

//then sum the widths
double totalWidth;
for(Double tempWidth:widths)
    totalWidth+=tempWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Collection` of type `Box` and add each box to it as you go. Then you can simply use a `for` loop.

```
public class Box {
    int width;
    public Box(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
}

...

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Collection<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<Box>();
    boxes.add(new Box(1));
    boxes.add(new Box(2));
    boxes.add(new Box(3));
    boxes.add(new Box(4));

    int total = 0;
    for(Box box : boxes) {
        total = total + box.getWidth();
    }
    System.out.println("Total widths: " + total);
}
```